# EasyMotion repeat

Tags: vim

I've replaced my fFtT completely with EasyMotion's equivalent and I've found it to be adequate in most cases except when I need to repeat the last motion with text objects. For example, dot command following ct or cf don't work the way they're supposed to. Is there a way make this work somehow, or do I have to resort to mapping the original ftFT for cases like this?

Answer (score 0):

I try to be bold, without testing and say, NO, it cannot be repeated.

you typed some magic key (for example, **f** . Default `<leader><leader>f`), triggered easyMotion, try to move to letter `x`. but on your current screen, there are 10 `x` after your cursor. Then you typed `c` to move to the right one. now you try to type dot `.` to repeat it. how easyMotion know which `x` you want to go to next?

Comment: Well I'd like it to repeat exactly what I typed. If I typed 'c' to move to the right one, I'd like it to type 'c' as well when it repeats. The reason I'm repeating is because the structure of the texts are similar, so using the same character to get me to the next position will work for me most of the time.

Comment: then I guess everytime you played with easymotion, you have to store the key sequences into some register/variable, when you typed ".", you check that variable. however you have to distinguish that what would you repeat after pressing dot. since it could be, easymotion key pressings, then `dd` removed a line, then "dot" should repeat 'dd'.

Comment: Yea, looks like there's no easy solution to this. I'll also look into vim-repeat and see if it's easy to integrate EasyMotion to use it. For now, this feature is critical enough for me that I'm remapping my EasyMotion keys to be <Leader>ftFT instead and reverting back to the default ftFT behaviors.

Comment: Just a little comment. I think it's better to learn to use vim as it is original with movements, it would take longer to learn but will be quicker when used. And has more options. But that is a matter of taste of course.

Comment: @244an we should know the original, but for daily usage, better make it be comfortable for self using. otherwise, no customized mapping, plugins should be done, to stick with "original". my 2cents